# What do you do first - light the Chanukia or read the Migillah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Let's say you do Tosefet Yom Tov on Chanukah.

Some people just add a couple hours, but some people are really-extra-super-Machmir and light till Purim.

What do you do first - light your Chanukah candles and then go hear megillah, or hear megillah and then go light?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

You hear megillah first because of a gezera (or a rabbinic concession to socio-halachic reality, depending on how you view these things). If you're doing tosefet chanuka until purim, then there's no real reason to stop there instead of going on till Pesach. To preven this, chazal decreed that you read Megillah first, then get drunk after megillah reading which means your wife won't let you near the candles and you won't light.

Comment: "of going on till Pesach" And why did Chazal want to avoid this? (melacha issues, perhaps?)

Comment: melacha issues can be gotten around, but sufganiyot are chometz!

Comment: :) maybe you should [edit] that in?

Answer (score 3):

The major concern is that since you have an obligation mehadrin min hamehadrin to light all hundred of your candles at one go, a person waiting till nightfall will miss the megillah.

Optimally, you should FIRST go to megillah reading, since it's period of persumei nissa is zmano oveir, and only AFTERWORDS light your channukiyah so people walking home from shul will see your house burning down.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended practice is to couple this with Tosefes Purim and get plastered the previous afternoon.  Then, you should light the Megillah and read the Chanukiah.

Answer (score 1):

tadir v'she'eino tadir, tadir kodem. Since lighting menorah is 8 times a year and megillah is only twice, menorah comes first

Comment: But then you might miss Megillah, as it would probably take a long time to light all those candles.

Comment: But we read megilla on 4 other occasions too spread around the year!